# LinkedIn REST API Cant Send Message; Couldt parse mailbox-item document: error: Unexpected end of file after null

Tags: django, linkedin-api

Im using Linkedin Rest Api on a site im building, in general works great  the only problem is that i cant send messages to my connections.

```
({'status': '400', 
  'content-length': '302',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
  'vary': '*',
  'server': 'Apache-Coyote/1.1',
  '-content-encoding': 'gzip',
  'date': 'Wed, 28 Mar 2012 22:52:35 GMT',
  'x-li-request-id': 'QU0G42N6TV',
  'nncoection': 'close',
  'x-li-format': 'xml',
  'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8'},
  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  \n<error>\n <status>400</status>
  <timestamp>1332975155652</timestamp>
  <request-id>QU0G42N6TV</request-id>
  <error-code>0</error-code>
  <message>Couldn\'t parse mailbox-item document: error: Unexpected end of file after null</message>\n</error>\n'
```

this how i call the api:

client.request(url,'POST','text/xml',param)

where:

```
url = 'http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/mailbox'
```

param:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><mailbox-item>
<recipients>
<recipient>
<person path='/people/TquMAMeCCD' />
</recipient>
</recipients>
<subject>Congratulations on your new position.</subject>
<body>Youre certainly the best person for the job!</body> </mailbox-item>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Typically that error is returned when the API endpoint receives an empty document - can you verify that param is being sent correctly? I'm not familiar with django, where i`s the` `.request()` method implemented?

Comment: Yea you were right!, also the header was not in the right format. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Problem was finally on the header, i wasn't setting the right content-type. That fixed it.

Comment: What was the content type you needed to sent?

Comment: header = {"Content-Type":"application/json"}